# Tool for Memory Use Tracking in OpenCV JNI library used in Java Application

Tags: java, opencv, memory-management, memory-leaks, java-native-interface

What are the tools available to track memory allocated by Opencv JNI library in Java Application.

In my java dropwizard server, I use JNI opencv bindings. While the server is on, java heap memory does not seem to be increasing beyond a GB, it is regularly freed by GC. But huge (4-5 GB) amount of memory is being added to the java process, not sure where it is coming from.

How can the memory allocated in JNI library be tracked and identify if any leaks.

Comment: `valgrind`, but you can also use tools that are coming with your system. Here (for example) you have a sample that shows memory leaks inside `JNI` code using `Instruments.app`: https://youtu.be/0CAuWuMkKBM

Answer (score 7):

The response of @concision is correct, for such need, you can indeed rely on [jemalloc](http://jemalloc.net) to capture where malloc is called and visualize the allocations as a picture or pdf thanks to `jeprof`.

When I was personally looking for a way to detect a native memory leak, I quickly found several articles that describe the idea in general but I could not find any article that describes how to do it step by step, so I will try to do it in my answer.

---

## Add the leaky endpoint

As you meet your issue with a dropwizard application, let's create a leaky endpoint as example.

Let's add our leaky endpoint in [dropwizard-example](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/tree/v2.0.13/dropwizard-example).

1. Clone the repository with `git clone git@github.com:dropwizard/dropwizard.git`
2. Switch to the last tag with `git checkout v2.0.13`
3. Add the leaky class `LeakObject` in `dropwizard-example/src/main/java/com/example/helloworld/api/`
4. Add the endpoint class `MemoryLeakTestResource` in `dropwizard-example/src/main/java/com/example/helloworld/resources/`
5. Register the endpoint in `dropwizard-example/src/main/java/com/example/helloworld/HelloWorldApplication.java`

**The class `LeakObject`**

```
public class LeakObject {
    private static final byte[] ZIP_CONTENT;

    static {
        try {
            ZIP_CONTENT = Files.readAllBytes(
                Paths.get("target/dropwizard-example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar")
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public String buildSaying() throws IOException {
        // The native memory leak is caused by the unclosed ZipInputStream
        ZipInputStream inputStream = new ZipInputStream(
            new ByteArrayInputStream(ZIP_CONTENT)
        );
        return String.format(
            "Hello, I'm a leak in native memory %d !", inputStream.read()
        );
    }
}
```

**The class `MemoryLeakTestResource`**

```
@Path("/native-memory-leak")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public class MemoryLeakTestResource {


    private final LeakObject leakObject = new LeakObject();

    @GET
    public String sayHelloWithLeakNative() throws IOException {
        return leakObject.buildSaying();
    }
}
```

**The class `HelloWorldApplication`**

```
public class HelloWorldApplication extends Application<HelloWorldConfiguration> {
    ...

    @Override
    public void run(HelloWorldConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) {
        ...
        environment.jersey().register(new MemoryLeakTestResource());
    }
}
```

---

## Build the application

In a terminal:

1. Go to the directory `dropwizard-example`
2. Build the project with `mvn clean install -DskipTests`.

This will create a fat jar in `target` called `dropwizard-example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

---

## Install `jemalloc`

To avoid being tightly coupled with the target environment, let's use docker for this task.

To install `jemalloc`, we need to:

1. Download the sources from github
2. Configure the build using `./configure --enable-prof --enable-debug` in order to enable the heap profiling and the leak detection functionality
3. Build it with `make`
4. Install it with `make install`

**The corresponding `Dockerfile`**

```
FROM openjdk:11-slim

ARG JEMALLOC_VERSION=5.3.0

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y tcpflow vim htop iotop jq curl gcc make graphviz bzip2 && \
    curl -O -L https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/releases/download/$JEMALLOC_VERSION/jemalloc-$JEMALLOC_VERSION.tar.bz2 && \
    tar xjvf jemalloc-*.tar.bz2 && \
    rm jemalloc-*.tar.bz2 && \
    cd jemalloc-* && \
    ./configure --enable-prof --enable-debug && \
    make && \
    make install && \
    cd - && \
    rm -rf jemalloc-*

WORKDIR /root
```

To build your docker image:

1. In a terminal, go in the directory that contains your `Dockerfile`
2. Then launch the build command `docker build -t native-memory-leak .`

This will create a docker image with `java` 11, `jemalloc` and `jeprof` installed

---

## Launch the application with `jemalloc`

For this you will need to:

1. Set the environment variable `LD_PRELOAD` to the location of the library `libjemalloc.so`
2. Set the environment variable `MALLOC_CONF` to `prof_leak:true,prof_final:true` in order to enable the leak reporting and to make it dump the final memory usage to a file (named according to the pattern `<prefix>.<pid>.<seq>.f.heap`) on application exit
3. Launch your java application

Those steps can be done with a command of type:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libjemalloc.so \
    MALLOC_CONF=prof_leak:true,prof_final:true \
    java ...
```

---

## Strategy to identify a native memory leak with `jmalloc`

1. Launch the java application as described previously
2. Launch your stress test
3. Stop the application
4. Launch `jeprof`

### 1. Launch the java application

We will launch the application within a docker container.

So first, let's start the container with the next command:

```
docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd):/root \
    --name native-memory-leak-test native-memory-leak /bin/bash
```

This command will launch a bash in a container called `native-memory-leak-test` based on the image `native-memory-leak` with the content of the current directory (that we assume to be `dropwizard-example`) available from `/root`.

From this bash, you can launch the application using the command described previously which will be in our case:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libjemalloc.so \
    MALLOC_CONF=prof_leak:true,prof_final:true \
    java -jar target/dropwizard-example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar server example.yml
```

Once the application is fully started, we can go to the next section

### 2. Launch your stress test

In this step, the idea is to call several times the endpoint that causes the memory leak to ensure that the leak will clearly appear in the final report.

In this case, we will call 2000 times the endpoint from a new terminal with the next command:

```
docker exec -it native-memory-leak-test \
    /bin/bash -c "for i in {1..2000}; do curl -s localhost:8080/native-memory-leak > /dev/null; done"
```

This command will call 2000 times the endpoint using a `curl` command

Once the command is over, we can go to the next section

### 3. Stop the application

In the container in which we launched the application, we can stop it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to dump the memory usage into a heap file of type `jeprof.<pid>.0.f.heap`

You should then see in the standard output of the application something like:

```
<jemalloc>: Leak approximation summary: ~<total-bytes> bytes, ~<total-objects> objects, >= 37 contexts
<jemalloc>: Run jeprof on "jeprof.<pid>.0.f.heap" for leak detail
```

This indicates that jemalloc has generated a heap file whose name is `jeprof.<pid>.0.f.heap`.

### 4. Launch `jeprof`

From the previously generated heap file, we will use `jeprof` to generate a human-readable output with the next command.

```
jeprof --show_bytes --gif $(which java) jeprof.<pid>.0.f.heap > result.gif
```

This command will generate a gif file called `result.gif` in `dropwizard-example` from `jeprof.<pid>.0.f.heap` thanks to `jeprof`.

The resulting gif should be a tree of allocations where the trunk is **"os malloc"** representing what has been allocated by the JVM. Your leak, if any, will be disconnected from the tree like in the next example:

[image: Example of jeprof result]

In this example, we can see that we have a leak caused by "`Java_java_util_zip_Inflater_init`" but we still need to identify the java code that calls this native method in our application.

See also [Use Case: Leak Checking](https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/wiki/Use-Case%3A-Leak-Checking)

---

## Spot the leaky code

At this point, we know that we have a leak but we still need to spot where it is located in our application. For this part, the best approach I could found, is to use [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) (it is a commercial profiler but you can use a trial key).

Here are the steps to do:

1. Launch your Java application on your host
2. Launch your JProfiler on your host
3. Click on *"Attach to a running JVM"*
4. Select the JVM corresponding to the application, then click *"Start"*
5. Choose the profiling mode *"Async sampling"*
6. Edit the settings of the mode *"Async sampling"* to check *“Enable sampling of native libraries”*, then click *"OK"*
7. In *"CPU Views"*, click to record CPU Data
8. Launch your stress test
9. In *"CPU Views"*, go to *"Call Tree"*
10. Click on the menu item *"View"* / *"Find"* to input the FQN of the native method to find (in our case it would be "`Java_java_util_zip_Inflater_init`")

With this approach, I can see in the next screenshot that my leak occurs in the method `com.example.helloworld.api.LeakObject.buildSaying` as expected.

[image: JProfiler CPU Views]

Answer (score 3):

Hunting down memory leaks allocated from JNI libraries is a bit more of a painful process than hunting memory leaks on the heap. The tool [`jemalloc`](http://jemalloc.net/) might interest you, as it can help isolate where a large amount of allocations are coming from in native memory allocations. You can then use the `jeprof` tool to generate a graphic to visualize the stack where significant allocations happen.

Take a look at these articles with issues that are very similar to yours:

- https://technology.blog.gov.uk/2015/12/11/using-jemalloc-to-get-to-the-bottom-of-a-memory-leak/
- https://www.evanjones.ca/java-native-leak-bug.html

They detail the process of hunting down their memory leak, caused by a JNI library (i.e. memory was *not* on the heap).